# Как переносить введенный текст в RememberEditText на последующие Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, activity

Приветствую! У меня есть 3 разных Activity, каждая из них открывается последовательно друг за другом, при это на них должны выполняться следующие операции:
1-ое Activity: На нём находятся несколько полей RememberEditText, задающие наименования, которые при переходе на следующий Activity, будут переноситься в TextView на следующем Activity, т.е. 2-ом.
Закодил я это следующим образом:

```
    cel = (RememberEditText) findViewById(R.id.cel);
    kr1 = (RememberEditText) findViewById(R.id.kr1);
    kr2 = (RememberEditText) findViewById(R.id.kr2);
    kr3 = (RememberEditText) findViewById(R.id.kr3);
    postrresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postrresh);
    postrresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent4 = new Intent(Activity1.this, MessageActivity1.class);
            intent4.putExtra("message1", cel.getText().toString());
            intent4.putExtra("message2", kr1.getText().toString());
            intent4.putExtra("message3", kr2.getText().toString());
            intent4.putExtra("message4", kr3.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent4);
```

Здесь перенос выполняется, введённый текст без ошибок переносится.

2-ое Activity: На данном Activity должен быть обработан вывод введённого в RememberEditText ранее текста, что я оформил следующим образом:

```
    celzadach = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.celzadach);
    Intent intent5 = getIntent();
    String message1 = intent5.getStringExtra("message1");
    celzadach.setText(message1);
```

Кроме того, на 2-ом Activity нужно как и на 1-ом обработать перенос текста, при переходе только уже на 3-ий Activity, я попробовал импортировать переменные под которыми функционируют RememberEditText, и обработать ранее показанный вариант переноса, но компилятор ругается на getText.

В сложившейся ситуации, как мне перенести введенные наименования из RememberEditText, на 1-ом Activity, в TextView, на 3-ей Activity, находясь при этом на 2-ом Activity?

Comment: передавайте в третью активити message1 (и остальные) из второй активити, зачем вам получать их из первой, если они есть во второй. Нужно понимать, что если активити не на экране, то она условно не существует и вы не можете получать из не какие-либо данные или содержимое виджетов

Comment: Брррр.... Зачем для такой легкотни создавать ЦЕЛУЮ АКТИВНОСТЬ? Это же просто против здравого смысла. Используйте фрагменты, `ViewPager` и т.д

Comment: на 3-ей активити мне нужно перенести содержимое других RememberEditText, которые есть только на 1-ой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте переменные во 2 Активити. Присвойте им getExtra из первой Активити. Установите их значения в textView, а когда будете переходить на 3 Активити передайте эти переменные аналогично передаче из 1 во второй активити.

Comment: Создать совершенно новые переменные и приравнять их к  переменным, относящихся к RememberEditText на 1-ой Activity, я правильно вас понял?

Comment: @Sir.. Стоят три человека. У первого в руках кружка с чаем. Он может налить второму этот чай сразу в рот (textview), а может в кружку(переменная), если та у него есть. Второй, если без кружки, вынужден будет чай сплюнуть третьему, тоже в рот, если третий без кружки, а если есть, то в кружку. Пусть у второго тоже будет кружка. И выпить сможет (установить значение в textview) и налить третьему(передать интентом).